# Add next non-used digit to value

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Is there a formula, or series of formulas, that I can use to copy the value from a cell in the same row and add the next non-used digit to it? See image for desired result.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your original list is in column A, starting at `A1`, in `B1`, put this and drag down:

```
=A1&"-"&COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)
```

Note that this works specifically for the data you show here.

Answer (score 1):

In **B1** enter:

```
=A1 & "-" & 1
```

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=A1,A2 & "-" & --MID(B1,LEN(A2)+2,9999)+1,A2 & "-" & 1)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Comment: Just wondering why the relatively complicated construct for the counting? Any difference in that and `COUNTIF()`?  Edit: Ah, I think that this will restart numbering if "alpha" appears in say row 13, so `B13` would be `alpha-1`?.  Is that correct?

Comment: @BruceWayne  You are 100% correct!!  Your formula is the best one if there are no repeated **blocks**, only repeated **items** within a block!